# how to pivot using javascritpt?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm facing an array of objects where it is possible to have more than one object with the same value of `id`. When the value of `id` is the same, the value of `price` will also be the same.

Here's an example:

```
[{
    'id': 'A', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 1
}, {
    'id': 'A', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 2
}, {
    'id': 'B', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 1
}]
```

The result should be an array where only one object appears for every `id`. Moreover, `quantity` must be populated with the sum of the quantities in the repeated values of `id`.

Here's the expected result for the example above:

```
[{
    'id': 'A','price': 1, 'quantity': 3
}, {
    'id': 'B','price': 1, 'quantity': 1
}]
```

Actually, I need to pivot.
I would like to avoid jQuery and external calls. Is it possible to accomplish this using only JS functions?

Comment: Did you try writing the code for that? What did you find difficult here using loops and sets?

Comment: I don't see any pivoting involved, this is more of an array merge based on some criterion.

Comment: Hi, since I'm using Google Tag Manager I can't use the scripts you provided because it doesn't support ECMASCRIPT6.

Comment: @Giulio: See my updated answer :-)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of objects are a little messy to work with, but this is do-able.

```js
const list = [
    {'id': 'A', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 1},
    {'id': 'A', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 2},
    {'id': 'B', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 1}
];

// Objects are easier to work with. An intermediate step to combine entries by Id.
const intermediate = list.reduce((a, { id, price, quantity }) => {
  a[id] = a[id] || { id, price, quantity: 0}; // Copy id & price if the entry doesn't exist yet.
  a[id].quantity += quantity;                 // Add quantity.
  return a;
}, {});

// Map it all back to an array of objects.
const result = Object.keys(intermediate).map(id => intermediate[id]);
console.log(result);
```

Here's a ES5 version:

```js
var list = [
    {'id': 'A', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 1},
    {'id': 'A', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 2},
    {'id': 'B', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 1}
];

// Objects are easier to work with. An intermediate step to combine entries by Id.
var intermediate = list.reduce(function(a, curr) {
  a[curr.id] = a[curr.id] || { id: curr.id, price: curr.price, quantity: 0}; // Copy id & price if the entry doesn't exist yet.
  a[curr.id].quantity += curr.quantity;                 // Add quantity.
  return a;
}, {});

// Map it all back to an array of objects.
var result = Object.keys(intermediate).map(function(id){
  return intermediate[id];
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Prices do not add up.

Comment: Eh, yes they do. Did you look at the result? `{id": "A", "price": 2, "quantity": 3`}

Comment: @Cerbrus be Op does not want that.

Comment: Indeed I did, did you?

Comment: Right, missed that, @Werner. Answer fixed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe not efficient, but does its work.

```js
const array = [{
'id': 'A', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 1
},{
'id': 'A', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 2
},{
'id': 'B', 'price': 1,  'quantity': 1
}];

const aggregated = array.reduce(function (p, c) {
  if (!p[c.id]) p[c.id] = {quantity: c.quantity, id: c.id, price: c.price};
  else p[c.id].quantity += c.quantity;
  
  return p;
}, {});

const final = Object.keys(aggregated).map(function(k) { return aggregated[k]; });

console.log(final);
```

Comment: Hi unfortunatly the tag manager I use doesn't support ECMASCRIPT6. Can you change the code plaese?

Comment: `Array.prototype.reduce()` is ES5.1 https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce as well as `Object.keys`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, it's very simple to understand:

```js
var objs = [
    { 'id': 'A', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 1 }, 
    { 'id': 'A', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 2 }, 
    { 'id': 'B', 'price': 1, 'quantity': 1 }
];

const results = objs.reduce(function(acc, current) {
  var obj = acc.find(function(o) {
    return o.id === current.id && o.price === current.price
  });

  if (obj) {
    obj.quantity += current.quantity;
  } else {
    acc.push(current);
  }

  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(results);
```

Comment: Hi unfortunatly the tag manager I use doesn't support ECMASCRIPT6. Can you change the code please?

Comment: Just replace `let` by `var` and you are done, check my answer again :)